# Why "get message" is wrong but "get messages" is right?

Tags: grammar

Why is

> People can get message from their friends through the internet

Grammatically incorrect? What rule is it that forces the above sentence to be "get messages" and how can I make sure I remember this pattern in the future?

Comment: If you mean that more than one message may come then you need the plural "messages". If you want to talk about one message at a time then you need "a message". (Sorry I can't point you to a "rule" you can remember.)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to use the singular would be

> People can get **a** message from their friends through the internet

That's because messages are countable and **every singular countable noun requires a [determiner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/grammatik/british-grammar/determiners)**, which can be an article (a/an/the) or some other word that specifies that countable object.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's some general concept of messages?

Comment: @theonlygusti: some words are used as both uncountable and countable: _communication_, for example, can be used in a general sense, and is then uncountable (example from  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/communication): "The node had established communication with the network, but had as yet sent no data"); and also to refer to a single event of communication, when it is countable ("I have received a communication from the lawyers"). But not all nouns can be used in both these ways, _Message_ happens to be countable only, and cannot be used to mean some general concept.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that you always have to say "get messages" or "get a message" (the same in this context), never "get message". English speakers do not usually like a countable thing without an article.

Comment: What's an example of an unusual case where it's fine to use a countable noun without an article?

Comment: Oh I just didn't want to promise that there were no exceptions because this is a language of exceptions. I'm not sure there are any but let me think about it.

Comment: I think you can *only* "use a countable noun without an article" if that noun is *also* capable of being used as a ***non-count noun***. So *I always have **[a] coffee** after dinner* is fine with or without the article, but *I always have **a cigarette** after dinner* is invalid without the article, because *cigarette* can only be countable.